# Data from API error [Can't resolve all parameters for UserService: (?).]

Tags: typescript, angular

Currently I have a small API where I am retrieving some user data from as I am learning angular2.

I created a user class [`user.ts`]:

```
export class User {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
}
```

Then the service [`user.service.ts`]:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {User} from '../models/user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

export class UserService {
    private usersUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/user';
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.usersUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

I have a home component where I am trying to display the list of users for testing purposes (user list to be changed to a component later).

```
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service'
import {User} from "../models/user";

@Component({
    selector: '<home>',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/user.component.html',
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    users: User[];

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {

    }

    getUsers() {
        this.userService.getUsers().then(users => this.users = users);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getUsers();
    }
}
```

I provide the service in my `app.component.ts:`

```
providers: [
        UserService
    ]
```

and finally I try to display the data:

```
<div *ngIf="users" class="ui celled animated list">

    <div *ngFor="let user of users" class="item">

        <div class="content">
            <div class="header">{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</div>
            {{ user.email }}
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

The JSON being retrieved is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "first_name":"Jameson",
    "last_name":"Ziemann",
    "email":"hank.runte@example.net",
    "created_at":"2016-07-07 06:24:25",
    "updated_at":"2016-07-07 06:24:25"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, first of all you need to add the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to the providers array:

```
providers: [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    UserService
]
```

And second, you need to make your service injectable, so Angular 2 knows, that it actually has to resolve the constructor arguments via dependency injection:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {User} from '../models/user';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable() // <-- annotation for Angular 2
export class UserService {
    private usersUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/user';
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }
```

Also in your `UserService` you try to access a `data` property after deserializing it, where you already get the array. Consider removing it like so:

```
getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.usersUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: So I did what you said, no errors are being displayed anymore, but the data isn't being shown, in the HTML I get : `template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
}` so I guess it's not setting the users property, but in the network monitor I can the data getting returned from the /user URL, any idea why this would be?

Comment: No idea to be honest. The code and flow looks fine to me.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: Ah, remove the `data` after `response.json()`.

Comment: Ah yes, now it works, I looked at that part earlier but thought it had something to do with just getting the data from the JSON response, thank you.

Comment: Good one. Keep it.